# SDB upload optimisation

Tags: upload, jena

I need to load around 10000 entities in Jena SDB every 3 hours
but the first upload itself is taking lot of time around 2 hours.
I am using Jena API to upload the data and my SDB is backed by MySql

I am sure I am doing something wrong.

Please tell me how to increase the speed of upload.

I am using following commands

```
 store.startbulkUpdate();
 store.getDataset.getdefaultmodel.add(modelWithData);
 store.finishbulkUpdate();
```

Do I need to specify chunk size etc?
Also what is an  optimum configuration for mysql?

Comment: You'll probably get a better answer from the jena-users mailing list where there are other SDB users.

How big is an entity, in terms of triples? (i.e how big is modelWithData)?  Which version are you running?   Is the MySQL DB local or remote?

Comment: 1 entity has around 8 triples. I am using latest Jena and SDB. MySql DB is local

Comment: I tried getting in jena users mailing list but ti is not happening